# What are the formal terms for the properties of an ordering of a number system

Tags: inequality, terminology

EDIT:
I suppose the following is also a necessary property of our comparison system - what is its name? I realise it’s an extremely basic one but in any abstract order perhaps it is necessary to define it.

$$a=b\implies f(a)=f(b),\forall f:\mathbb{C}\to\mathbb{C}$$

OP:
A video on the proof of the inability to “properly” order the complex numbers stated the following properties as necessary conditions for such an ordering:

$$\begin{align*}
\\&1)\quad a<b\text{ or }a>b\text{ or } a=b
\\&2)\quad a<b,b<c\implies a<c
\\&3)\quad a<b\implies b>a
\\&4)\quad a<b\implies a+x<b+x,\forall x\in\mathbb{C}
\\&5)\quad a<b\implies ax<bx,\forall x>0
\\&6)\quad a<b\implies ax>bx,\forall x<0
\end{align*}$$

I think I am right in saying that the first three conditions are properties of a “total order”, but I could find no other term that captured the final three conditions. I believe also that $1)$ is known as the trichotomy property, $2)$ is the transitive property, $3)$ is the reflexive property, but I do not know the names of the last three, or whether the last three are direct conclusions from the first three.

I am asking the formal name for such an ordering under arithmetic as described above (since the only ordering terms I found were to do with sets in general and not arithmetic in those sets) and what the formal names, if any, there are of the last three conditions.

Many thanks.

Comment: What is "our comparison system"?

Comment: The complex numbers have no order. Neither $i>0$ nor $i<0$ is valid. Both possibilities lead easily to a contradiction using the necessary properties for an order.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA the abstract ordering of the complex numbers that the video author wanted to prove was impossible; such an ordering necessarily had to have all of these (very basic, common) ordering properties, a fairly natural assertion to make

Comment: @Peter I know! The proof follows from the conditions of such an ordering above - I ask for their names...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's called an [ordered ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordered_ring) (or in this particular case an ordered field). The point of the final three conditions is that the ordering plays nicely with addition and multiplication.

If we didn't have such requirements, then ordering $\Bbb C$ would be no trouble at all. There are plenty of ways to totally order $\Bbb C$. But none that behave the way we expect orderings to behave with respect to arithmetic.

Comment: Since here the inequalities are strict, this is sometimes rather called an ordered domain. For instance, the ring $\mathbb{R}[x] /(x^2)$ of dual numbers can be ordered by setting $a+b x <c+d x$ if $a<c$ or $a=c$ and $b<d$, and this yields an ordered ring rather than what the OP is asking.